# Calling methods on integers fails, doesn't on floats

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer

I noticed a rather strange behaviour for integers, which doesn't apply, for example, to floats or decimals:

```
In [205]: 10.__add__
File "<ipython-input-205-24ed61a2ee18>", line 1
10.__add__
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This does not happen for floats or decimals:

```
In [211]: Decimal(10).__add__
Out[211]: <bound method Decimal.__add__ of Decimal('10')>

In [204]: 10.3.__add__
Out[204]: <method-wrapper '__add__' of float object at 0x7fb48c60f840>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parser is expecting the period to be the decimal point of a float. Make it explicit to the parser what you mean.

```
(10).__add__
```